# Preventing xmlhttp function from running again on keyup

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax, xmlhttprequest

So I have a keyup function that retrieves data from a MySQL table, and then displays it. However, it retrieves data again if a letter is changed.

See image below
[How it currently is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SKuUu.jpg) and [In the inspector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JGWEI.jpg)

What it should be doing is just replacing those suggestions with the new suggestions instead of adding it on to the list

**EDIT: Shoaeb's solution works but not in the way he suggested.**

```
document.getElementById('schoolListMenu').innerHTML="";
```

**I added that line right after the keyup function is called. This clears the content in the div and replaces it with the updated content once the user has stopped typing. If the user presses a key again it will clear the div again and append the updated results.**

**edit2: Updated JS Code**

```
var timeout = null;
function getSchool(schoolType){
    if(schoolType1.classList.contains('active') || schoolType2.classList.contains('active'))
    {
        schoolNameField.onkeyup = function(e)
        {
            document.getElementById('schoolListMenu').innerHTML="";
            clearTimeout(timeout);
            timeout = setTimeout(function() {
                var query = e.target.value;
                console.log(query);
                var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                    if (this.readyState === 4 && this.status === 200) {
                        var schoolResult = this.responseText;
                        schoolResult = schoolResult.split("|");
                        for(var i = 0; i < schoolResult.length; i++)
                        {
                            var schoolSuggestion = document.createElement('div');
                            schoolSuggestion.id = 'schoolSuggestion'+i;
                            schoolSuggestion.className = 'item';
                            schoolSuggestion.innerText = schoolResult[i];
                            document.getElementById('schoolListMenu').appendChild(schoolSuggestion);
                        }
                    }
                };
                xmlhttp.open("GET", "scripts/schoolLookup.php?type="+schoolType+"&name="+query, true);
                xmlhttp.send();
            }, 500);
        };
    }
}
```

How do I get it to replace the content instead of adding on new divs? I feel like I understand what the problem is and know what the solution is but I can't put it to words

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this line

**document.getElementById('schoolListMenu').appendChild(schoolSuggestion);**

to

**document.getElementById('schoolListMenu').innerHTML(schoolSuggestion);**

or you can clear the list before appending

**document.getElementById('schoolListMenu').innerHTML="";
document.getElementById('schoolListMenu').appendChild(schoolSuggestion);**

Comment: This solution worked but not in the way you thought. I understand why you suggested that. I put this line "document.getElementById('schoolListMenu').innerHTML="";" right after the on key up. So if the user types again the entire div is emptied until they stop typing. I'll post the complete solution in the post edit

Comment: if you are using html5, you might find this intresting....
https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_datalist.asp